# Replacing an object while keeping references to it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Say I have a living object of a certain type. Some other objects possibly keep references to it.

Now I need to 'substitute' this object with its descendant (i.e. a more 'specific' clone of it), and all the objects that had a reference to the old one should be pointing to the new object. (Given that the new object is a descendant of the old one, the referees should not even notice the difference; but this is just a matter of validity).

This could technically be done either by creating a new object and then updating the references in some way, or by dynamically changing the type of the existing object, so that the references would be the same. (But the latter conversion is narrowing, which presents some problems).

Is there a normal .NET way of achieving this? (Either VB or C#).

Comment: Do you have any code of the inheritance, because this is a little complex and depending on your implementation the solution is different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty much reinventing [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (or at least a variation thereof) here:

```
interface IBehavior
{
    int DoFoo();
}

class Proxy : IBehavior
{
    public IBehavior Strategy { get; set; }

    public int DoFoo()
    {
        return Strategy.DoFoo();
    }
}

class BasicBehavior : IBehavior { ... }

class AdvancedBehavior : IBehavior { ... }
```

Now, with all this you can:

```
class Consumer
{
    public IBehavior Behavior { get; set; }
}

// Keep reference to behavior somewhere handy
var behavior = new Proxy { Behavior = new BasicBehavior() };
var myConsumer = new Consumer { Behavior = behavior };

// Now myConsumer is using Basic Behavior

behavior.Strategy = new AdvancedBehavior();

// ...and now myConsumer is using Advanced Behavior
```

Comment: How to I change the strategy in your example?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Good example, but does `Proxy` need to implement `IBehavior`? seems like you could just go straight to the `Consumer` - Actually I see sorry.

Comment: Well, it all comes down to having a 'plug-in' field in the original object. That's what I've done before; I just didn't know it was called a 'strategy' ;) But apparently, this is the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a simple, builtin way of doing this. I can think of two "workarounds".

1. Create a "wrapper class" that only contains a property for the object you want to replace later. Make all the references to an instance of that wrapper instead of the object itself.
2. Create a single element collection (a simple array, for example). Exchange element 0 as needed and make the references point to the array.

Example for 1:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public BaseClass TheObject { get; set; }
}

Wrapper reference1 = new Wrapper();
reference1.TheObject = new BaseObject();

Wrapper reference2 = reference1;
Wrapper reference3 = reference1;

reference2.TheObject = new DerivedFromBase();
```

Example for 2:

```
BaseObject[] reference1 = new BaseObject[1];
reference1[0] = new BaseObject();

var reference2 = reference1;
var reference3 = reference1;

reference3[0] = new DerivedFromBase();
```

1) is the one I'd go with.

Comment: 1) is not too dissimilar to what @Anton proposed; just having an interface can make things a bit cleaner. 2) is a very 'Pythonian' (and generally scripting) way of doing things. Clever but a bit cryptic semantically.

Comment: @Zeus Yes, actually I came up with this without knowing about the "Strategy Pattern" :-) It just seemed logical doing it this way. The pattern goes a bit further in that it delegates every interface method to the assigned strategy, while my approach doesn't require interfaces at all. Seems you need to decide which one is easier for you to implement. My approach seems more universal in that it works with any class (if you change `TheObject` to be of type `object`) while the Strategy pattern is "safer" in that it defines operations using an interface.